# What parasites would be easiest to examine using a compound microscope?

Tags: parasitism

I want to find some parasites that are easy to examine under the microscope. 
I'm a beginner but I have an olympus microscope with total magnification up to 400x (also 200x, 100x and 10x).

I would like to choose parasites that are safe for me as an amateur to work with and would like to have one that parasitizes people.

I prefer lets say:
Helminths, mycose (*Candida alba*) or something that can make people sick and is safe to work for someone who is an amateur.

Comment: You don't need microscopes to observe some parasites (for e.g. leech). So you should clarify what kind of parasites you are interested in.

Comment: You should also specify how you plan on getting ahold of parasites that can make people sick because that likely limits your options.

Comment: I suggested an edit to your question that includes changing "Helmits" to Helminths — if that isn't what you meant can you clarify what Helmits are?  Also I'm not sure that a microscopic human parasite is ever going to be "safe" for an amateur to work with — can you add something to your question to clarify why you want to do this?

Comment: Yes safity is very important. So I dont want anything that is dangerous. So I want to examine them under the microscope.

Comment: Lets say mycose and to choose candida alba, how to grow them cultivate and examine under microscope? So first question is then how to cultivate it (grow), control it and then as last step examine them undet microscope? Or should I start with beer mycose, that is safer and after that to start with othes spicies?